# Disable part of an Input element

Tags: javascript

I am using intl-tel-input [library](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) for international phone number inputs. However I am only looking to allow users to select or change a country code but not enter a new phone number. So I am wondering how I can disable the phone number input but keep the countrycode dropdown

[image: Phone Number Input]

if I use the disable attribute on the input it does not allow country code selection. So this dropdown doesn't work when disable is used.

[image: country code dropdown]

Ideally users wouldn't be able to even click into the input (except for the dropdown piece)

```
<div class="slds-var-p-top_xx-small">
  <input  type="tel" class="slds-input" data-id="contactPhoneInput" name="country" value={user.Contact.Phone}></input>
</div>
```

//Javascript

```
const TELINPUT = window.intlTelInput;
const INITIALCOUNTRY = "us";
const PREFERREDCOUNTRIES = ["us", "ca", "mx"];

createPhoneInput(TELINPUT, TYPE) {
        const INPUT = this.template.querySelector(`[data-id=${TYPE}Input]`);
        this.intlTele[TYPE] = TELINPUT(INPUT, {
            utilsScript: RESOURCE_utilsjs,
            initialCountry: INITIALCOUNTRY,
            preferredCountries: PREFERREDCOUNTRIES
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please include the html and your attempts to achieve this.

Comment: Included html in original question

Comment: you should work on some javascript that on change of the input will prevent the modification. What have you tried so far? Your only attempt is to modify an html attribute on the whole field?

Comment: There has to be more to it; that html isn't enough to generate what you're showing your screenshot.